# Testing Angular Router with promise then

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, angular-router

I am testing the following code:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home']).then(() => {
    window.location.reload(); 
});
```

When I try to test this I will get

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Is there a proper way to test this?

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: checkout https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/routing/

Comment: When testing are you providing router as a Jasmine spy?

Comment: I used const routerMock = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') }

Answer (score 0):

```
const router = { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve()) };
```

and add in providers

```
{provide: Router, useValue: router}
```